# Finding all occurrences using rfind, flow challenges?

Tags: c++, string, workflow

Following a c++ tutorial and teaching about `find()` the following code was implemented to search for all the "cat" occurrences in a `string`:

```
std::string input;
std::size_t i = 0, x_appearances = 0;
std::getline(std::cin,input);   
for(i = input.find("cat",0); i != std::string::npos; i=input.find("cat", i))
{
    ++x_appearances;
    ++i; //Move past the last discovered instance to avoid finding the same string
}
```

Then the tutorial challenges the apprentice to change `find()` for `rfind()`, and that's where the problems came in, first I tried what seemed to be the obvious approach:

```
for(i = input.rfind("cat",input.length()); i != std::string::npos; i=input.rfind("cat", i))
{
    ++x_appearances;
    --i; //Move past the last discovered instance to avoid finding the same string
}
```

but with this solution I fell into an infinite loop. Then I discovered that it was happening because the increment is performed before the condition check, and that the increment `rfind()` was always finding a match even with `i==std::string::npos` (if the match is on the beginning of the string, for example "cats"). My final solution came to be:

```
int n=input.length();
for(i = input.rfind("cat",input.length()); n>0 && i!=std::string::npos; i=input.rfind("cat", i))
{
    ++x_appearances;
    n=i;
    --i; //Move past the last discovered instance to avoid finding the same string
}
```

With `n` I can keep the track of the position in the `string`, and with it exit the `for loop` when the entire `string` had been searched.

So my question is: Is my approach correct? Did I need an extra variable or is there any other simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i = input.rfind("cat",input.length()); i != std::string::npos; i=input.rfind("cat", i))
{
    ++x_appearances;
    --i; //Move past the last discovered instance to avoid finding the same string
}
```

The problem with the above is the `--i` inside the loop. Suppose the input string starts with "cat". Your algorithm will eventually find that "cat" with `i` being 0. Since you've declared `i` as a `std::size_t`, subtracting 1 from 0 results in the largest possible `std::size_t`. There's no warning, no overflow, no undefined behavior. This is exactly how unsigned integers must work, per the standard.

Somehow you need to handle this special case. You could use an auxiliary variable and a more convoluted test in your loop. An alternative is to keep your code simple and at the same time make it blatantly obvious you are explicitly handling this special case:

```
for (i = input.rfind("cat"); i != std::string::npos; i=input.rfind("cat", i-1))
{
    ++x_appearances;
    // Finding "cat" at the start means we're done.
    if (i == 0) {
       break;
    }
}
```

Note also that I've changed the loop statement a bit. The default value for `pos` is `std::string::npos`, which means search from the end of the string. There's no need for that second argument with the initializer. I also moved the `--i` into the update part of the for loop, changing `input.rfind("cat",i)` to `input.rfind("cat",i-1)`. Since `i` is always positive at this point, there's no danger in subtracting one.

Comment: Ah yes much more graceful to handle the special case! I also appreciate the simplifications proposed, the default pos value and the modification of i to the update part of the loop :)

Comment: Another option is to use the tertiary operator in the update clause of the for loop, thereby getting rid of the if statement inside the loop: `for (i = input.rfind("cat"); i != std::string::npos; i = i ? input.rfind("cat", i-1) : std::string::npos)`. Personally, I find the `if` statement much more readable, more understandable, and more maintainable.

Comment: Yet another solution :) I was going to ask if the tertiary operator was well constructed but now I understand it. It will be true as long as `i>0`, and false when the special case is reached.